# Custom function writing on calculator

Tags: function, statistics, calculator, ti-basic

I'm sitting here with my TI-89 Titanium and having fun writing some custom functions for this test on friday.

Question:
`bmp(b1,b2,b3)
Func
binompdf(b1,b2/100,b3)*100`

What do I need to input to make the result show with a % symbol in the end? So instead of jut displaying a 20, it would display 20%?

Please share your tips and tricks if you have any, would be greatly appreciated.

Btw if anyone is curious the test is in calculus, integral, vectors and more.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the functions output to a variable (say test_var.) 
Then try:
   Disp test_var & "%"

or, more rudimentary:
   Disp test_var & "percent"